# How to add typing file for third library?

Tags: typescript, type-declaration

I'm using a third library that withou `types` declaration file. So I need to  add the typings for the library in my project.

But I had tried it many times with always wrong result.

Here is my `tsconfig.json` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "types": ["node"],
    "strict": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

I created a `global.d.ts` file in my root project and declared the module:

```
declare module 'matrix-js-sdk' {
  interface Promise {
    done(callback: () => void): void
  }

  interface Client {
    joinRoom(roomId: string): Promise
  }

  export function createClient(options: {
    baseUrl: string
    accessToken: string
    userId: string
  }): Client
}
```

Import third library:

```
import sdk from 'matrix-js-sdk'
// error: Cann't find the declaration file for the module 'matrix-js-sdk'
```

In addition, I also tried to create `root/src/@types/matrix-js-sdk/index.d.ts` file and write the declaration:

```
interface Promise {
  done(callback: () => void): void
}

interface Client {
  joinRoom(roomId: string): Promise
}

export function createClient(options: {
  baseUrl: string
  accessToken: string
  userId: string
}): Client
```

But it never works.

---

**================== Updated ====================**

Now I can write declaration in `src/global.d.ts` **(not root project)**, and refer it to be included in compilation:

```
/// <reference path="../global.d.ts" />

import sdk from 'matrix-js-sdk'
```

But the `reference` syntax is not recommended, and I tried to include the `src/global.d.ts` in `files` field in **tsconfig.json**:

```
"files": ["src/global.d.ts"],
"include": ["src/**/*"],
"exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*", "**/*.spec.ts"]
```

It throw the same error again:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'matrix-js-sdk'
```

**Another**, the `src/@types/matrix-js-sdk/index.d.ts` still not works(I prefer to use this way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try to put

```
declare module 'matrix-js-sdk' {
  interface Promise {
    done(callback: () => void): void
  }

  interface Client {
    joinRoom(roomId: string): Promise
  }

  export function createClient(options: {
    baseUrl: string
    accessToken: string
    userId: string
  }): Client
}
```

in `src/@types/matrix-js-sdk/index.d.ts`

also there is no default export in your declaration file so `import sdk from...` will give some errors related to that.

Comment: You are right! Thanks!  
And there is need to configure the `typeRoots` in **tsconfig.json**: `"typeRoots": ["./src/@types", "./node_modules/@types"]`

Comment: Do you know the issue of `global.d.ts` above?

Comment: I've moved `src/@types/matrix-js-sdk/index.d.ts` to `src/global.d.ts` and vscode still able to navigate to the correct `d.ts` file without `files` property in `tsconfig.json`